# Update answer's creation time to last change if somebody edits his answer during 5min grace period

Tags: feature-request, edits

I came to [that SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15151739/curl-post-not-working-php) and seen that there was only Hanky Panky ㇱ's answer. When I came, this answer was :

> Most probably it is the SSL verification problem.
>
> Add
>
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); curl_setopt($ch,
>   CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

I wanted to add my 2 cents and given another answer. Some secs after, I reloaded page and seen that Hanky Panky ㇱ's answer changed, and now integrated my answer unfairly (without "as Ninsuo's mentionned" or other things that let create an unique good answer fairly for those who added their hits). As comment suggests, it may have not done it intentionnaly, that's not the point.

His answer's creation date was still before mine, so my answer comes as a partial duplicate of Hanky Panky ㇱ's one.

For the OP's question, both of our answers were not the solution. But, I believe this could be a good idea to update the creation time to the last change during 5min grace period.

*Thanks to @tohecz that given a simpler solution to the problem (I origninally thought about creating a new review history).*

Comment: A user gets a 5 minute grace period during which they can make any edits to their post without creating a new revision in the history. Anything after that *will* create a new revision.

Comment: I know, and that's a good idea for small mistakes (such as english for non-native speakers, or formatting). And this leads to my request :-)

Comment: If a question is simple / common enough, I think it's reasonable to assume that more than one person could come up with the same answer at the same time.  It may not have been intentional / malicious.

Comment: IMHO the official time of a post should refer to the last change within those 5 minutes. That would solve it.

Comment: I don't see a problem, almost every question on SO gets answers which are equal.

Comment: @tohecz, absolutely.

Comment: @Ninsuo: Well, you should place *that* as your feature request. Because this is unlikely to be accepted as a feature. tohecz idea might though.

Comment: As for the first revision of this question: see [Make first draft of a new answer part of the permanent revision history](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138017/make-first-draft-of-a-new-answer-part-of-the-permanent-revision-history).

Comment: What problem does this solve? As far as I can tell, there is no real problem here. So there are two largely similar answers. That happens all the time (and not merely by users copying content from others). It seems you're merely frustrated with the particular user. If so, I would say "move on".

Comment: I am not. And I thought by using a question where both of us gave 0-voted non accepted answers there may not have any ambiguity on that point

Comment: @Ninsuo Okay, great. :) But then why this request? What is the problem it solves? How does it improve the site? If you're not upset about the situation, then why would there still be a need for this?

Comment: That's a *problem* of credibility: imagine a simple but multiple-answer question given on a popular tag. 5 guyz give 5 good answers, but the first answerer, after some minutes(less than 5) put the 4 other answers on its own. And I am a newbie that comes to SO and see that the first answer (with the earier creation date) contains everything. I will say to myself "wow, why everybody answered smaller answers next?".