# Is it valid to use &nbsp; to edit answers and remove the original under 5 mins?

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-answers

Recently a 133K user answered a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17173660/html-abnormal-behavior-of-hyperlinks/17173729#17173712), which was totally a wrong answer (No doubt, we all make mistakes, doesn't matter), but later he edited the answer using `&nbsp;&nbsp;` and so on, and the original post was lost, is this a valid way to do so?

Should there be something like if answer is deleted, also show the edits which were done within 5 mins?

[image]

Comment: He deleted it too. Why would we need to see what he edited? We all make mistakes, why difference does it make?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Probably higher rep users can edit the answer and cast an undelete vote..(Which is what the feature is for *undelete*), and I am not sure mods can see that or not, it's not just about this post, am talking in general, also keeping answer with `&nbsp;` wont be helpful to even mods when they are reviewing a user

Comment: @Mr.Alien: I don't think this is ever a real problem, no, even in general.

Comment: If you want mod input: I do this too, and none of the staff or other mods have taken issue with it.

Comment: This specific case aside, maybe you'd like [Make first draft of a new answer part of the permanent revision history](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138017/make-first-draft-of-a-new-answer-part-of-the-permanent-revision-history).

Comment: There are more restrictions on this than there used to be. HTML comments used to work. Since these have been implemented I've noticed a tendency for people to do the same thing by typing 30 characters of garbage so this actually seems a lot neater and a good workaround.

Comment: Happens all the time: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8403413/352552

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I see no problem it.  Apparently he said something very silly and wanted to hide his shame, even from 10k users.

There's no reason for us to know what the content of an embarrassingly wrong answer is except to satiate our curiosity.

There actually is an edit history feature here, except after you make a post or an edit, you have a grace period to fix your post before it makes an entry in the edit history.  this user deleted his post within a minute of making it, which is well within the grace period.

I'd leave it be.  It's benign.

Comment: Why shame? No one's perfect.. and am not talking about only this guy, am talking about users with low rep, will be useful for mods to see the edit history if the answer is deleted

Comment: @Mr.Alien There is an edit history, but there's also a grace period in which you can make edits before an official entry is made.  In the case where someone posts something that they later decide that they very soon realized that they didn't want to post why do you need to know what that was?

Comment: In order to use this "work around", the author would need to be aware of this potential workaround, know that you have a 5 minute edit grace period, and know that the answer was bad enough to warrant this action within that 5 minute grace period.  My guess is this impacts a very small subset of questions and answers, and probably not worth the effort to implement.  And that still doesn't address the question is why is it worth it?  If the post was that bad, do we care?

Comment: agreed tats why am suggesting to show edit history under 5 mins if answer is deleted, because these things are important for mods to review a users profile

Comment: @Mr.Alien why is it important?

Comment: @SamIam Ask mods, I asked once why we keep deleted answers, they told it helps them to review users activitiess

Comment: @Mr. Alien: This stuff is harmless. Even if somebody were doing this to hide abuse, either he doesn't repeat the behavior and everything is cool, or he gets caught eventually.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Oh ok, I just suggested to show edit history even if it's deleted under 5 mins ;)

Comment: *"Apparently he said something very silly and wanted to hide his shame, even from 10k users."* Why? Maybe he was just fast to realize, and changed within the 5 minute grace period *only* because he realized that soon. Not waiting for the grace period to have ended indicates *nothing* here, I'd say. Using whitespace instead of "Sorry, wrong answer" or "Sorry, answered wrong question" also means nothing to me.

Comment: @Arjan since the post was only there for a brief period of time, there were no edit wars, lengthy comment threads or other sources of drama that needed to be moderated.  The post is very insignificant.  there's no reason to know what's in it.

Comment: *"there's no reason to know what's in it*, indeed! But you're boldly assuming the author wrote something *"very silly"* and maybe *"an embarrassingly wrong answer"*...? I'm just saying we cannot know.

Comment: @Arjan  It's very clear that he didn't want anyone to see what he had wrote

Comment: @SamIam But that doesn't establish anything about why he didn't want anyone to see it.

Comment: Why is that *"very clear"*? Should he have waited until the grace period was over, *just* to keep some history? What's the point in that? Also, it might have been a totally unintended copy & paste in the wrong place, which indeed he might not have wanted others to see, but how is that the same as *"he said something something very silly and wanted to hide his shame"*...? You're just guessing, I feel.

Comment: @Arjan It's clear because if he didn't care whether or not people saw it he wouldn't have bothered to edit the content away at all

Answer (score 7):

Two benefits I'm seeing here:

- It removes all the content from the post. For a particularly long answer which gets deleted, this can greatly reduce the amount of space the deleted answer takes up on my screen. Reserving screen space for a useless self-deleted answer isn't very useful.
- It prevents them from being drawn back into the question later. Other high-rep users could potentially vote to undelete the answer, which would make him a part of the question again. No one in their right mind will undelete an answer that has no content.

After all, it is a *deleted* answer. No one under 10k can even see it, so why does it really matter? Do you have some particular benefit you'd gain from seeing the original answer that a user felt was so wrong that they not only deleted it, but removed all the content as well - other than just curiosity?

This behavior does absolutely no harm to the site, so there's no reason to install additional features to account for it. If a user continually deletes posts with zero or negative score, the content within them will not matter to the automated ban (but this particular user will never see that).

Comment: Especially the first point is why I'd do the same, though with "Sorry, wrong answer" rather than whitespace. And I'd also not explicitly *wait* for the 5 minute grace period to pass, if applicable, but remove as soon as I see my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure the user recognized their error after re-reading it (maybe MORE than 5 minutes later) and decided to reverse himself.  Since the answer has no bearing on other answers received, as the answerer felt it was incorrect, the proper response is to move on.