# Why doesn't an answer show up as having been edited if it has been replied to within the grace period?

Tags: discussion, edits, comment-replies, grace-period

I asked a question earlier and I received a reply with a minute of posting. It didn't answer my question and I replied to state why it did not answer my question. Within that period someone else had also replied.

The answer was then edited several times but the "edited [time] ago" didn't appear because it had been edited within the grace period. This now meant that the replies looked crazy and irrelevant.

Unfortunately the answer has since been deleted from the thread so I cannot link it to demonstrate.

---

I didn't know users with 10k rep can see deleted posts. So here's the thread:
[Working with time values greater than 24 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18303301/working-with-time-values-greater-than-24-hours)

Comment: If you still have the link to the question, 10k users can see the deleted answer.

Comment: @icktoofay Ahh, I did not know that. I'll add it to the OP.

Comment: Related [Make first draft of a new answer part of the permanent revision history](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138017/145673) but not a duplicate.

Comment: I do think a reply of any kind should trigger a revision, for situations just like this.

Comment: This is why I don't bother commenting on trigger-happy answers. Downvote and move on... you don't get into arguments about whether the answer is correct or not after it's been revised 10 times.

Comment: If there are comments that are no longer relevant, flag as obsolete , or in the case of multiple comments, flag one comment for a comment cleanup, and a mod will remove the outdated info