# Can very low quality flags remain on closed question

Tags: feature-request, low-quality-posts

I recently found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20274802/joptionpane-how-to-instantiate) that had been vandalised by it's author during the grace period to "nvm fixed it myself" after it was closed as "unclear". As a grace period edit it cannot be rolled back. Normally such a question could be flagged as "Very Low Quality" with the hope that a 10k user would delete the question. However because the question was closed only 3 options are available:

[image]

Obviously it makes sense to remove all the closure flags, but as a recommend deletion is it possible for the VLQ flag to remain

> it is very low quality. This question has severe formatting or content
>   problems. This question is unlikely to be salvageable through editing,
>   and might need to be removed.

In the end I flagged as 'other (needs ♦ moderator attention)', however, this seems non ideal as it pushes the flag to the highest level whereas any 10k+ user could have dealt with the question.

Comment: Wow. Now there's an edge case... :)

Comment: A couple days ago, I answered a question within less than a few minutes of it being posted. The author then edited the question to 'thanks to the answer, I solved it..'... The question is now gone, and my answer is somewhat useless. Everything was later deleted. Regardless, it probably should have been deleted from the first place anyways, as it was a crap question to begin with. In this instance it would have been nice to flag it as VLQ after it was closed.. 1+.

Comment: @JoshC No good deed goes unpunished

Comment: Peripherally related, possibly of interest: [Make first draft of a new answer part of the permanent revision history](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138017)

Comment: Mod flags for recommend deletion get declined most of the time anyway.