# Editing wrong answer to be a copy of correct answer

Tags: discussion, answers

I ran into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20823102/get-data-from-sql-in-one-array) where something rotten happened:

1. A user posted a [wrong answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20823102/get-data-from-sql-in-one-array#20823129)
2. After this, user Barmar posted correct answer
3. After this, the first user edited their answer to be a copy of Barmar's answer, so looking at the answer time, it looks like they posted their answer BEFORE Barmar!

I flagged the answer, but looking into the user's history, they did it [again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20617100/php-converting-integer-to-date-reverse-of-strtotime/20617144#20617144) and [again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20090795/some-problems-in-this-code/20090860#20090860)! Shouldn't the user be banned or something?

Comment: Might still be innocent - the user might have figured how to fix/improve his answer on his own. No need to ban anyone.

Comment: (The user has changed their username; so I edited a bit. Given that the name "user876345" did not match the actual user id in the URL, maybe this user was merged from 2 or more other users?)

Comment: See also [Make first draft of a new answer part of the permanent revision history](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138017/make-first-draft-of-a-new-answer-part-of-the-permanent-revision-history).