# Cap number of answers for new users

Tags: feature-request, post-ban, rate-limiting

I found [an user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2919798/user876345) who posted 790 trivial, low-voted answers in two months... wait, that's more than 20 answers per day! Isn't it too many, too low quality?

He is 6k rep now, but his answers are [controversial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214092/editing-wrong-answer-to-be-a-copy-of-correct-answer) sometimes.

Shouldn't be the number of answers capped to some reasonable number at least for new users?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214092/152859 (same user reported)

Comment: Generally No. And specifically this users answers are totally fine too. I picked 3 answers at randon and they were neither copied nor low quality.

Comment: [His latest answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20823653/1438393).

Comment: So, when we get a new user, who is really knowledgeable and can write great answers and who wants to be prolific with their answers, they should get capped?

Comment: @Oded: The limit can be imposed based on the quality of their answers (use upvotes/downvotes for this purpose). If they are posting good answers, they shouldn't get capped. But if they receive too many downvotes (maybe above a defined threshold), they get capped.

Comment: @AmalMurali - we do have a quality ban for answers as well. That's what it is for.

Comment: @Oded it seems it kicked in too late this time, doesn't it?

Comment: @JanDvorak - don't think so. Looks like someone who learned how to answer questions. There are a few answers with a score of 3 and above. Not saying the answers are stellar, but they are not terrible either.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Also related http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214106/why-did-my-reputation-drop-with-message-some-problems-in-this-code (the OP there is the same person).

Comment: @MartinSmith he does appear to edit his answers after other answers are posted, sometimes during grace period so it's not visible, and fixing/improving his own answer. Given enough of these and it's indeed kind of rude behavior - expected behavior is to delete your own wrong answer, I do it many times myself. Not saying he's always doing it, but saw more than a few and in the improved answer he's not really adding anything beyond the newer answers posted after his own. No ban is needed for this, but I can totally justify the downvotes he's getting.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes editing your wrong answer to repeat a correct one in the grace period is pretty poor.

Comment: @Martin, for that specific answer on the deleted question, does its [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20090860/revisions) show the copying behaviour? (If yes, then a comment on the Meta question you found might be nice, to let the user know it's not appreciated and that the lost rep was actually not earned nicely.)

Comment: @Arjan - No. That one doesn't show any signs that I can see.

Comment: Thanks, @Martin. Jan, I just found Google's cache ([screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wW7tI.png)) for that specific question. And while both answers look very much the same, both also copy a lot of text from the question. That makes it easy to come up with the same answer. (Even when the first revision was wrong, the edited version might still be that user's "own work". Still then, I would have deleted my answer when the other post was correct before mine was, but well...)

Answer (score 2):

Setting a hard ceiling for the number of answers for anyone is not a good idea, whether they are [Blankman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/39677/blankman) or [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet). We cap questions for a reason: to stop the help-vampires from posting 30 questions a day instead of researching their code. However, there's no reason to reciprocate this with answers; answers (I think) are valued higher than questions here.

If the user's answers are low-quality enough, they'll be auto-banned until he asks good questions and edits his poor answers. Alternatively, if they've copied answers from another user, you can flag them for plagiarism. Also consider leaving a comment on some of their answers and letting him know the problem