# Why did my reputation drop with message "Some problems in this code"?

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

Recently, in my Stack Overflow account reputation reduced with the reason of "Some problems in this code".  How to know which answer or section has problems for the above mentioned reason? It helps me correct the problems myself. Can any oneshare their thoughts on this?

[image]

Also, I have searched for the phrase "Some problems in this code" in the "Deleted Recent Answers" section of my account, but I wasn't able to find anything.

Comment: Regarding your most recent edit I probably confused the situation by editing the title of the offending deleted question. It is now titled *What is the reason for this syntax error?*. Not *Some problems in this code*

Comment: And here's a [screenshot of the entire question](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PfVCD.png). Note that Martin has since edited the title.

Comment: @Mysticial Could you just... open your inbox? :-P That red 11 is driving me crazy!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I bet that the, "Some problems in this code" isn't a *reason*.
But rather, it's the title of a [question that you answered that was deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20090795/some-problems-in-this-code). ([screenshot for < 10ks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfVCD.png))

When a post gets deleted, all rep that is gained/lost from it is usually reversed. If you have 10k, the title will link through to the question.

So in this case, you got mislead by that (horrible) question title.

Comment: Yes I agree, If Question deleted by the moderator, the reducing reputation is fine. But I got the specific message `Some problems in this code`

Comment: @ChinnuR where did you see this reason?

Comment: When a post gets deleted, it will show up in your rep history as "removed  *title of question*". In your case, I'm guessing the title is actually "Some problems in this code" which would be very misleading. (unless I've completely misinterpreted your question)

Comment: @ChinnuR very hard to believe that's a reason moderator will leave. Please take a screenshot and edit into your question here.

Comment: Yep. [This answer was deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20090860/73226) along with the question by three 20K users.

Comment: Reason seeing in `http://stackoverflow.com `

Comment: @MartinSmith Nice find! Dunno how you found it. I've added the link to my answer.

Comment: @ChinnuR we figured that, I was trying to figure out where precisely you saw this message, but I think Martin figure it out.

Comment: @ChinnuR - I've retitled the question. You should just see `What is the reason for this syntax error?` now!

Comment: @MartinSmith post mortem edit, that's a nice one! but how **did** you find it?

Comment: @ShadowWizard - Top Google result for `Some problems in this code` for me.

Comment: @MartinSmith that's... just genius! ;)

Comment: @martin wait, Google can search among deleted content?

Comment: @JanDvorak Google crawled and indexed it before it got deleted.