# Show every edit in the question revision history

Tags: feature-request, edits, revisions-list

I'd like to propose that all edits performed on a question are visible in the review history. Specifically, I'm asking that the five minute grace period goes away from the perspective of the revision history.

I still think a five minute window needs to exist in terms of the community-wiki edit count. I don't want people shying away from small corrections and typos in their own questions, for fear of turning their question into a CW.

This has several benefits:

- It can help reduce confusion when answers/comments are [rendered obsolete by changes to the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138017/make-first-draft-of-a-new-answer-part-of-the-permanent-revision-history#comment387564_138017) within the first five minutes.
- It can provide valuable insight into the history of the question; it can be helpful to see how the OP is responding to comments.
- It may help users understand badly worded questions – often these are caused by multiple edits without much thought to the overall structure.
- It can make it easier to see when a 2k+ user is mid-way through an edit spree. This might help avoid mid-air edit collisions.

There are potentially some down-sides, of course:

- Noisy revision histories. Personally I think the benefits outweigh this down-side. It's not *that bad* to see some additional revisions.
- Embarrassment. You can't hide your spelling/grammar mistakes. Oh well!
- Performance - storing additional revision data in the database will impact performance. Is this significant and can this be managed?

I think complete transparency is a good thing on this site and matches well to the values of openness and ownership of content.

<sup>(Inspired, in part, by [Make first draft of a new answer part of the permanent revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138017/make-first-draft-of-a-new-answer-part-of-the-permanent-revision-history))</sup>

Comment: The other issue is performance.  Lots of extra revisions means storing all of that data in the DB.  My guess is this would be pretty significant.

Comment: @Duncan You're putting the performance there as a question.  It's not a question.  It *will* have a negative performance impact (more in space than in time, I'd guess).  It's merely a question of degree; whether or not it's a prohibitive problem or a manageable one.

Comment: @Geobits I'm not sure how seeing the edit history of *questions* will affect FGITW justice. I think Shog9's argument applies only to answers.

Comment: @Servy Yup, I agree. That's what I meant by my original wording, but I've adjusted it to be clearer.

Comment: the vigilante justice statement is a strawman rooted in fear, antipathy, and/or lethargy. it's a misrepresentation of both intent *and* proposed utility of the original request in the linked post.

Comment: @Servy i've been assured that these revisions are stored in the DB already.

Comment: @swasheck By whom? Do you have a link to cite?