# Preventing abuse of the grace period

Tags: discussion, grace-period

From time to time I have noticed what I only can describe as an abuse of the 5 minute grace period when answering a question.

1. User posts a short incomplete answer, just to be the "first answer" of a question.
2. User edits this answer frequently for 5 minutes, often adding information from other users answers, to make the answer better than the other answers.
3. User get lots of reputation due to being the "first answer" and being very "thorough", even though the user, in my opinion, doesn't deserve it.

Comment: Also see this related question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138017/make-first-draft-of-a-new-answer-part-of-the-permanent-revision-history