# How long is the question/answer edit grace period?

Tags: support, edits, grace-period

I have observed there is a period of time which edits can be made to a question or an answer within which the edits are not reported by SE as being edits.

There is sometimes a problem when user A makes a post, user B comments about something in the post, user A edits the post within the grace period with response to user B comment, then user C later comments chastising user B for not reading the post.

So I'm wondering how long this grace period is.

Comment: Per [How does editing work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work), 5 minutes.

Comment: @Spevacus 5 minutes or until a comment is made, the first among them. It's explained in the faq, but better have it here as TL;DR.

Comment: I have made comments and then received replies after an edit response, with the question showing no edits and subsequent commenter explaining that I don't know how to read the information in the question. This has happened many times.

Comment: *then user C later comments chastising user B for not reading the post.* flag such comments at a minimum as no longer needed, or even rude / abusive. We don't chastise user here, ever, no matter what the situation is.

Comment: [Related thoughts regarding answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138017/165455).